# Converting an IEnumerable to a lookup with multiple keys per value

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures, dictionary, lookup

What's the best way to transform an `IEnumerable` into a lookup- or dictionary-like structure, but with multiple keys per value?
What I'm looking for is something that does roughly the same thing as this, and in a generic way:

```
var wordsByLetter = new Dictionary<char, HashSet<string>>();
foreach (string word in words)
{
    foreach (char letter in word.Distinct())
    {
        if (!wordsByLetter.ContainsKey(letter))
        {
            wordsByLetter.Add(letter, new HashSet<string>());
        }
        wordsByLetter[letter].Add(word);
    }
}
```

So the result is a dictionary mapping each letter used to the set of words that contain that letter.
For example, if `words` contained `{"foo", "faz", "zoo"}` then the resulting dictionary would contain:

```
'a' -> {"faz"}
'f' -> {"foo", "faz"}
'o' -> {"foo", "zoo"}
'z' -> {"faz", "zoo"}
```

I could turn my code example into an extension method, but is there a built-in function or better algorithm to use?

Comment: How do you intend to use this data structure? What do you mean by multiple keys per value in this case?

Comment: @lpthnc: I've edited the question to try to clarify.

Comment: I edit my answer after you accepted it, you might be interested in the new version...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using `ToDictionary` :

```
var wordsByLetter =
    words.SelectMany(word => word.ToCharArray())
         .Distinct()
         .ToDictionary(
            letter => letter,
            letter => words.Where(word => word.Contains(letter)));
```

Note that it's certainly less efficient than your code, since the words collection is enumerated once to get the distinct letters, then once for each letter...

---

**Update:** actually I have a much more efficient suggestion :

```
var wordsByLetter = 
   (from word in words
    from letter in word
    group word by letter into grp
    select new
    {
        Letter = grp.Key,
        Words = new HashSet<string>(grp)
    })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Letter, x => x.Words);
```

It should give exactly the same result as your code

Answer (score 5):

ToLookup is the extension method you need. For example:

```
var lookup = (from word in words
              from c in word
              select new { Word = word, Character = c }).ToLookup(x => x.Character, x => x.Word);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) instead?

[C# implementation of a Trie](http://www.kerrywong.com/2006/04/01/implementing-a-trie-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

```
// { foo, faz } -> { f|foo, o|foo, f|faz, a|faz, z|faz }
var pairs = words.SelectMany(w =>
   w.Distinct().Select(l => new { Word = w, Letter = l }));

var map = pairs.ToLookup(p => p.Letter, p => p.Word);
```